# Mixed-effects modelling of pairwise changes (indirect change)

Tags: mixed-model, pre-post-comparison

It is straightforward to model "direct" changes using a mixed-effects model. Let's assume we have 3 correlated measures over time from a subject, `y1, y2 and y3`. One can model these three outcome variables directly by regressing against time (independent variable) in both random and fixed effects. However, I wonder how I could approach a problem in which I have `y1 - y2`, `y2-y3`, and `y3-y1`. In this case I do not have access to direct measures (`y1,y2 or y3`), but pairwise changes over time (that I call "indirect"). Perhaps I can use the interval between `y1-y2` and `y3-y1` as both random and fixed effects, but with this approach the meaning of time is quite different.

So the question is: how would you organise your data frame for this scenario? How would you define time? My aim is to calculate annual changes with the mixed effects model for example.

Comment: In "direct" model you check if measures change with time (time is your independent variable). What do you want to check in "indirect" model (what is your independent variable)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let's assume independent variable is time with some other nuisance variables. So, in this example, we could assume that we are looking at annual changes. I have also edited question for future readers.

Comment: So, what is `y1-y2`? Is it a difference between 1st and 2nd year?

Comment: yes exactly, it is difference over an interval.

Comment: I'd run repeated measures ANOVA to compare `y1 - y2`, `y2-y3`, and `y3-y1`, and see which changes differ significantly.

Comment: If I wished to have some other variables in model I'd just introduced factor (say A means change between 1st and 2nd year, B means change between 1st and 3nd year, C means change between 2nd and 3rd year) and used subject's ID as random effect

Comment: what if time interval was variable? You couldn't use factors. Also the comment about repeated measure ANOVA is good only if I had balanced design, in which case I wouldn't worry about mixed-effects.

Comment: No more ideas, sorry :(